# I am trying to pass skip some cases in assertion error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, combinations

Using command `py.test ./Combinatory_testing.py -v` on terminal to be able to run it in py.test 
When I run it ,it is giving me test failed because of the function "is_valid_combination" but the problem is that I want the assertion to be always pass and to just skip is_valid_combination cases, not to add it to the test.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
#importing libraries
from allpairspy import AllPairs
import pytest


#parameters are mainly:
#Computer names
# OS
# Network to be connected to these PC's
# Contract type for the employers

parameters = [
    ["HP", "DELL"],
    ["98", "NT", "2000", "XP"],
    ["Internal", "Modem"],
    ["Salaried", "Hourly", "Part-Time", "Contr."],
]

#Uncomment below to print all the possible Combinations with less numbers for sure using the function AllPairs

# print("PAIRS:")
# for i, pairs in enumerate(AllPairs(parameters)):
#    print(i,pairs)
#


def is_valid_combination(brand, operating_system, network, contract):
    """
    This is a filtering function. Filtering functions should return True
    if combination is valid and False otherwise.
    """

    # Brand DELL does not support Windows 98
    if "98" == operating_system and "DELL" == brand:
        return False

    # HP does not work with XP
    if "XP" == operating_system and "HP" == brand:
        return False

    # Contractors can't work on "Internal" network.
    if "Contr." == contract and network == "Internal":
        return False

    return True


#Uncomment below to print all the possible Combinations with less numbers for sure using the function AllPairs After Filtering the
#impossible combinations

#
#print("PAIRWISE:")
# for i, pairs in enumerate(AllPairs(parameters, filter_func=is_valid_combination)):
#     print("{:2d}: {}".format(i, pairs))

def function_to_be_tested(brand, operating_system, Network, Contract):
    return True

class TestParameterized(object):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(["brand", "operating_system", "network", "contract"], [
        value_list for value_list in AllPairs([
            ["HP", "DELL"],
            ["98", "NT", "2000", "XP"],
            ["Internal", "Modem"],
            ["Salaried", "Hourly", "Part-Time", "Contr."],
        ])
    ])

    def test_assert(self,brand,operating_system,network,contract):
        assert is_valid_combination(brand,operating_system,network,contract)
```

Comment: Please don't write so-called "Yoda conditionals. E.g. `if "XP" == operating_system` should be flipped to `if operating_system == "XP"`. This is a habit that programmers used to avoid missing an equal sign, before compilers and languages improved. It has no place in Python.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank for your suggestions will definitely do this

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention that the code example was taken and adapted from the library `allpairspy`: https://github.com/thombashi/allpairspy.  This library generates certain combinations from lists given as inputs.  But, you have deleted the named parameter `filter_func=is_valid_combination` from the call to `AllPairs`.  If I understand your problem correctly, adding this again will make sure only such combinations are generated, where your assertion will pass.